# How to make contract the owner of the tokens?

Tags: solidity

I am doing a test ICO on rinkeby testnet and the structure I am planning will be:

1. Deployed Token contract
2. Deployed ICO contract
3. ICO contract is the owner of the Token contract
4. I am the owner of the ICO contract
5. When the test user will send ether to ICO contract, ICO contract will trigger a function and send the test investor tokens from the Token contract.

The problem I am facing is that I don't know how to make the TOKEN contract the owner of the totalSupply tokens. What should the exact line of code be?

balance[X] = totalSupply;
where X is deployed contract address?
What should i write instead of X to make deployed contract the owner of all tokens?

Answer (score 0):

If your token is ERC20 (i assume?) and i correctly understood the question, then you can just mint it similar as described [here](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-solidity/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC20/MintableToken.sol)

Answer (score 0):

You could do it in your deployment I guess by deploying the ICO contract first, then passing the address in to your token contract as the owner address? (presuming you're using truffle)...

```
let Token = artifacts.require("./YourToken.sol");
let ICO = artifacts.require("./YourIco.sol");

module.exports = function (deployer)  {
    // Deploy the ICO First, and then we can use that address later:
    deployer.deploy(ICO).then(function() {
        return deployer.deploy(Token,ICO.address);
    })
};
```

Then as mentioned above run something like this as your constructor:

```
constructor (address _tokenOwner) public {
   _tokenOwner = totalSupply;
}
```

That might do it - I'm doing something similar the other way around.